# Find the area bounded by $x^2y^2+y^4-x^2-5y^2+4=0.$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

Find the area bounded by $x^2y^2+y^4-x^2-5y^2+4=0.$

---

I reduced the above equation to $y^2=\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+y^2-5}$ but i am not able to solve further.

Comment: It is better to isolate $x^2$

Comment: If we consider a circle $x^2+y^2=4$, then we can substitute $x^2=4-y^2$ and see that $(4-y^2) y^2+y^4-4y^2=0$ becomes an identity valid for any $y$. So, I'm pretty sure, the answer is just $4 \pi$.

Comment: The problem is unclear.  There are three bounded connected regions in the complement of the given curve.  Any of these three, as well as any union of threse three, can be considered an area bounded by the curve.  There are in total $7$ possible areas with $5$ distinct values ($6$ areas with $4$ distinct values if you only consider connected areas) to the question, and Yiorgos S. Smyrlis's answer $4\pi$ is a valid answer.  The given answer $\dfrac{4\pi}{3}+2\sqrt{3}$ comes from the region in between the two lines $y=-1$ and $y=+1$ inside the circle $x^2+y^2=4$.

Comment: Thank you,I understood

Answer (score 3):

Solve with respect to $x^2$ and obtain, for $y\ne \pm 1$, then
$$
x^2=-\frac{y^4-5y^2+4}{y^2-1}=4-y^2.
$$
Hence, circle of area $4\pi$.

**Note.** The points $(x,\pm 1)$, $x\in\mathbb R$, also belong to the
$$
x^2y^2+y^4-x^2-5y^2+4=0.
$$

Comment: Answer is $\frac{4\pi}{3}+2\sqrt3$

Answer (score 2):

This equation is equivalent to
$$
\left(x^2+y^2-4\right)\left(y^2-1\right)=0
$$
That is, this describes the union of a circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin and a horizontal line at $y=1$ and a horizontal line at $y=-1$. So, the enclosed area is inside the circle, which has area $4\pi$.

[image]